# Threading class to control Raspberry Pi GPIO

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi, gpio

I'm using my Raspberry Pi to control a relay as part of a watering system I'm building. I've finally got my threading class setup to create multiple threads based on a simple SQL Query. The following code is used to iterate through records and create each thread (the GPIO pin number and the duration of the delay to keep the relay open are passed over):

```
with con:

con.row_factory = lite.Row       
cur = con.cursor() 
cur.execute(joinProgramZoneQuery)
rows = cur.fetchall()        

for row in rows: 

    duration = int(row["programDuration"]) 
    deviceGPIO = int(row["deviceGPIO"])         

    t = MyThreadWithArgs(deviceGPIO=deviceGPIO, duration=duration)
    t.start()
```

The following is the class that I've created to handle each thread (well it's the whole class that is used to create a thread for each GPIO pin):

```
# use P1 header pin numbering convention
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)

class MyThreadWithArgs(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, deviceGPIO="default value", duration="default value", **kwargs):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self, **kwargs)

        self.deviceGPIO = deviceGPIO
        self.duration = duration       

    def run(self):

        logging.debug('Current GPIO pin: %s', self.deviceGPIO)       

        #SETUP THE PIN FOR OUTPUT AND DEFAULT TO LOW OUTPUT
        GPIO.setup(self.deviceGPIO, GPIO.OUT, initial=GPIO.LOW)
        #output the GPIO pin to HIGH                
        GPIO.output(deviceGPIO, GPIO.HIGH) 
        #Pause for specified duration        
        time.sleep(self.duration) 
        #SET THE GPIO OUTPUT BACK TO LOW AGAIN AFTER THE SLEEP
        GPIO.output(self.deviceGPIO, GPIO.LOW)
        #clean up all GPIO pins after the script has run..
        GPIO.cleanup()            

        logging.debug('ending')
```

The issue is that I'm getting a `RuntimeError: The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT` error when I have already set the output from the GPIO pin as being true. I even do a `GPIO.cleanup()` at the end of the class to ensure that it's not causing any issues once the delay has ended. It doesn't seem to always do it for every GPIO pin I've set, but it's always for at least 2..

I though this might have been an issue with the way that I'm creating an instance of the class, although when I remove the GPIO code it works without an issue (e.g. sleeps as required with multiple threads).

Is there something simple I'm missing here? Apologies in advance if I have! I'm fairly new to this..

Cheers

Comment: You have a typo `GPIO.output(deviceGPIO, GPIO.HIGH)` -> `GPIO.output(self.deviceGPIO, GPIO.HIGH)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that type out... unfortunately basically the same issue is still occurring. I get a    `GPIO.output(self.deviceGPIO, GPIO.LOW)
RuntimeError: The GPIO channel has not been set up as an OUTPUT` error every time I run the script... is there any other obvious issues with my code?

Comment: After some further trial and error, I worked out that the `GPIO.cleanup()` command was resetting the GPIO pins to input. I've removed and my script now seems to be working correctly. Well at least the GPIO pins are firing now without displaying the 'no output error'...